# Using default parent with multiple selectors in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Let's say I have the following HTML

```
<DIV id="root" my-custom-attribute>
  <BLOCKQUOTE>
    <P id="one">I should not work</P>
  </BLOCKQUOTE>
  <P id="two">I should work</P>
  <SECTION>
    <P id="three">I should work</P>
  </SECTION>
</DIV>
```

If I have one of the three P tags selected ( $('#one') for example), I can check that it is a specific type by doing:

```
$('#one').is('[my-custom-attribute] > P');  // false
```

Let's say that I have a set of selectors that I want to say would make the attribute "valid". So for example:

```
var selectors = '[my-custom-attribute] > P, [my-custom-attribute] > SECTION > P';
$('#one').is(selectors);  // will return false
$('#two').is(selectors);  // will return true
$('#three').is(selectors);  // will return true
```

Where in this case, I do not want to say the element is valid, if it is in the blockquote, but in the other 2 cases, it would be valid.

This list of valid selectors will be larger than this, but the common trait they all share is that I want the selector to start with the element that has the my-custom-attribute attribute.  Is there any way to write my selectors in an elegant fashion, where I don't have to start all the selectors with [my-custom-attribute]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var selectors = $('[my-custom-attribute]').find('> P, > SECTION > P');
$('#one').is(selectors);
$('#two').is(selectors);
$('#three').is(selectors);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/arunpjohny/UHabm/)

Comment: Ah, interesting. I hadn't thought about doing it this way. I'm going to try this out tonight, but this seems to be a nice solution.